# UIPrintInteractionController and UIDocumentInteractionController crashes when share button is tapped on iOS17

Tags: pdf, printing, ios17

I'm presenting the print view item of type NSData (this is a pdf that is generated), which I can view correctly in the print preview. I also tried to do this with UIDocumentInteractionController, I can successfully see the document. However, when the user taps on the share button, I get the following error:

```
error fetching file provider domain for URL:file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/.../tmp//PrintPreviewPDF/A0F77118-DC26-4682-98FB-159D3B01915F/Testing.pdf : (null)

Collaboration: error loading metadata for documentURL

Error acquiring assertion: <Error Domain=RBSServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "(originator doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.primitiveattribute AND originator doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.frontboard AND target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.trustedtarget AND Target not hosted by originator)"

Received port for identifier response: <(null)> with error:Error Domain=RBSServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "Client not entitled" UserInfo={RBSEntitlement=com.apple.runningboard.process-state, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Client not entitled, RBSPermanent=false}

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 

'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Cannot register subclasses in a bundle that hasn't been loaded!'
```

This worked perfectly fine before the iOS17 release. I have tried to not present the print screen as a sheet, and push it to the navigation stack instead. Doesn't help.

Edit: Happens with UIDocumentInteractionController and UIActivityViewController. Same crash, same errors.